# Followup email plugin JQuery error, but where?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a plugin that has a not defined error, I'm no developer and have searched to find out how fix this but without any luck.

Can someone please guide me on how to fix it.

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: So if there is no such function, you have to create one. Ask plugin owners for that or do `var init_fue_select = function () {};`

Comment: You do realize that empty function can bring even more issues? Because it has some purpose. In this case it seems to be initializing some select elements